# "Could not find declaration file for module" when the module is in tsconfig paths

Tags: typescript

I'm using [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) in an angular project. I have both `markdown-it` and `@types/markdown-it` installed as dependencies in my `package.json`. I want to pull in the minified file when building my bundle, so I've added an entry in my tsconfig's `paths` array:

```
[tsconfig.json]
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "../../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "markdown-it": [
        "node_modules/markdown-it/dist/markdown-it.min.js",
      ]
    },
    "module": "esnext"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tmp"
  ]
}
```

However, when I do the following in my component typescript file:

```
import MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it';
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'markdown-it'. '...../node_modules/markdown-it/dist/markdown-it.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

2 import MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it';
```

Without the paths entry in `tsconfig`, the error does not occur, but then it obviously doesn't pull in the minified file like I want. How do I use the `paths` alias while also telling typescript to use the `@types/markdown-it` typings?